# .htaccess rules to have CakePHP in root and WordPress in subfolder

Tags: .htaccess

How can I combine the .htaccess rules for CakePHP

```
RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

with the following

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} folder.yoursite.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder [L]
```

in other words redirect anything to app/webroot/ except /blog (which is an existing folder with a WordPress installation) and redirect blog.domain.com to the blog subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

It should work automatically (at least with CakePHP 1.3), it's working for me...

My .htaccess looks like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

You should also have **a proper .htaccess in your wordpress** (or any other application) folder that's not a part of the CakePHP application.